# Como utilizar processamento de linguagem natural em português com C#?

Tags: c#, padrão-de-texto

Eu preciso encontrar nome de pessoas e organizações no texto.

Descobri que preciso utilizar processamento de linguagem natural para isso, mas só consegui implementar em inglês utilizando Stanford NLP for .NET e OpenNLP.

Existe alguma forma de implementar esse recurso em português?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode achar modelos pré-treinados de várias linguagens (português inclusive) para OpenNLP 1.5 no seguinte link:

http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/